# Extract string between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I would like to extract characters between first opening and last closing brackets in a string like `match[input[name="firstname"]]` considering the characters to retrieve may also contain more brackets. In this case it would get `input[name="firstname"]` Also, the string may contain some special characters like `{ # / \ ^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This somehow awkward-looking regular expression

```
/[^[\]]+\[[^[\]]+\]/
```

basically says "no brackets, then [, then no brackets, then ]".

```
s = 'match[input[name="firstname"]]'
> "match[input[name="firstname"]]"
re = /[^[\]]+\[[^[\]]+\]/
> /[^[\]]+\[[^[\]]+\]/
s.match(re)
> ["input[name="firstname"]"]
```

To make this slightly more useful, here's how to extract topmost brackets' content from a string with respect to nesting:

```
function extractTopmostBrackets(text) {
    var buf = '', all = [], depth = 0;
    text.match(/\]|\[|[^[\]]+/g).forEach(function(x) {
        if(x == '[')
            depth++;
        if(depth > 0)
            buf += x;
        if(x == ']')
            depth--;
        if(!depth && buf)
            all.push(buf), buf = '';
    })
    return all;
}

text = "foo [ begin [bar [baz] [spam]] end ] stuff [one [more]]"

console.log(extractTopmostBrackets(text))
// ["[ begin [bar [baz] [spam]] end ]", "[one [more]]"]
```

Recursive matches support in a regex engine would allow to write that in one line, but javascript re's are not that advanced.

Comment: thx for your quick reply! I made an edit about some special characters in the string

Comment: @StephaneKouakou: this expr eats them all, since `[^[\]]` matches anything that is not [ or ].

Comment: @StephaneKouakou: Note that this won't work if you need to match multiple attributes, like `match[input[name="firstname"][type="text"]]` for which the above returns `"input[name="firstname"]"`.

Comment: If literally "between first instance of `[` and last instance of `]`, regardless of matching bracket", then `.match(/\[(.*)\]/)` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will match everything between the first occurrence of `[` and the last `]` in your string, no matter what characters are in between:

```
> s = 'match[input[name="firstname"]]'
"match[input[name="firstname"]]"
> re = /\[(.*)\]/
/\[(.*)\]/
> q = s.match(re)
["[input[name="firstname"]]", "input[name="firstname"]"]
> q[1]
"input[name="firstname"]"
```