# How to extract string match within brackets in R?

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract `"a", "b"` from `["a", "b"]`, where the Content within `[...]` is not known before doing the Operation. So `[...]` is the only identifier.

Normally, the extraction works like

```
stringr::str_match(string = ["a", "b"]', pattern = "LEFT(.*?)RIGHT")
```

So i have to find sthg along:

```
stringr::str_match(string = '["a", "b"]', pattern = "[(.*?)]")
```

but have to escape the brackets i guess.

```
stringr::str_match(string = '["a", "b"]', pattern = "[[](.*?)[]]")
```

Probably, now the brackets are escaped, but not `(.*?)`?

**What i tried:**

- Normally, i would escape the bracket `[` like `[[]` and use perl = TRUE. Therefore, i tried:

  `stringr::str_match(string = '["a", "b"]', pattern = "[[](.*?)[]]")`

  as shown above.
- Use regex like `/[^[\]]+\[[^[\]]+\]/` from [Extract string between brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536916/extract-string-between-brackets)

Comment: You can use `str_extract_all` i.e. `str_extract_all(string, "[A-Za-z]")`

Comment: Since you're just pulling stuff based on `[`, `]` pattern, you just need to escape the brackets properly like this: `stringr::str_match(string = "sss[a, b]sss", pattern = "\\[(.*?)\\]")`

Comment: ah nice thank you!

Comment: All you missed is that ICU regex requires escaping of `]` and `[` inside character classes. So, all you need is `stringr::str_match(string = '["a", "b"]', pattern = "\\[(.*?)]")[,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` which would directly extract the elements

```
library(stringr)    
str_replace(str2, "\\[([^]]+)\\].*", "\\1")
#[1] "\"a\", \"b\""
```

Or with `str_match`

```
str_match(str2, "\\[([^]]+)")[,2]
#[1] "\"a\", \"b\""
```

#### data

```
str2 <- '["a", "b"]'
```

Comment: thank you for the fast Response @akrun. If i am not mistaken, it would only extract the letters and not the full text. Desired Output is `"a", "b"`. I tried to modify to your answer to `[.*?]`, but i am not sure it is correct.

Comment: @Tlatwork do you want the quotes as well (updated the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str_extract`and positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\[).*(?=\\])")
```